# applying async/await to functions

Tags: javascript

I was following the documentation and not doing it right. Can someone take a look at my code and see what I'm doing wrong?

```
function getCookies(){

    var cookies = {
        art_rfp : '',
        art_token: '',
        hire_rfp: '',
        hire_token: '',
        corp_rfp: '',
        corp_token: '',
    }

    chrome.cookies.getAll({"url":"https://url.com"}, function (cookies) {
        var string = ''
        for(var i=0; i<cookies.length; i++){
            var name = cookies[i].name
            // console.log(name)
            if (name == 'a-sso_rfp') {
                console.log('ART- '+cookies[i].name+': '+cookies[i].value)
                cookies.art_rfp = cookies[i].value
            }
            else if (name == 'b-sso_token') {
                console.log('ART- '+cookies[i].name+': '+cookies[i].value)
                cookies.art_token = cookies[i].value
            }
            var value = cookies[i].value
            string += name+"="+value+"; "
        }
    });

    chrome.cookies.getAll({"url":"https://url2.com"}, function (cookies) {
        var string = ''
        for(var i=0; i<cookies.length; i++){
            var name = cookies[i].name

            if (name == 'a-sso_rfp') {
                console.log('HIRE- '+cookies[i].name+': '+cookies[i].value)
                cookies.hire_rfp = cookies[i].value
            }
            else if (name == 'b-sso_token') {
                console.log('HIRE- '+cookies[i].name+': '+cookies[i].value)
                cookies.hire_token = cookies[i].value
            }
        }
    });

    chrome.cookies.getAll({"url":"https://url3.com"}, function (cookies) {
        var string = ''
        for(var i=0; i<cookies.length; i++){
            var name = cookies[i].name
            if (name == 'e-sso_rfp') {
                console.log('CORP- '+cookies[i].name+': '+cookies[i].value)
                cookies.corp_rfp = cookies[i].value
            }
            else if (name == 'f-sso_token') {
                console.log('CORP- '+cookies[i].name+': '+cookies[i].value)
                cookies.corp_token = cookies[i].value
            }

        }
    });
    return cookies
}

function sendCookies(cookies){
    console.log(cookies)
}

console.log('this started')

async function run(){
    let cookies = await getCookies()
    let resposne = await sendCookies(cookies)
}

run()
```

When I print `cookies` in `sendCookies()`, it's printing before the browser gets the cookie data. I'm trying to make it wait until that is complete.

Comment: Can you tell us what your error is or what problem you're experiencing?  And what "documentation" are you referencing?

Comment: This link may be useful to you: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/javascript-from-callbacks-to-async-await-1cc090ddad99

Answer (score 3):

Your `getCookies()` function isn't asynchronous. It makes some async calls (`chrome.cookies.getAll()`), but doesn't wait for the results, instead returns immediately the `cookies` object.

You need to promisify the calls, something like

```
const getAllCookiesPromisified = (url) => new Promise(resolve => { 
   chrome.cookies.getAll({url}, resolve);
});

const p1 = getAllCookiesPromisified("https://url.com");
const p2 = getAllCookiesPromisified("https://url2.com");

return Promise.all([p1, p2]);
```

Comment: The code you wrote is different than what I'm reading in the documentation and still can't quite make sense of it. Is there a way I can send you a message?

Answer (score 0):

async/await works when the awaiting function returns a `Promise`. Both of your methods `getCookies()` and `sendCookies()` don't return Promise.

This blog [post](https://medium.com/@bluepnume/learn-about-promises-before-you-start-using-async-await-eb148164a9c8) might be useful for you.